# Kile - change color scheme for panels

Tags: color, kile

I'm trying to configure kile on my ubuntu 14.04. I have changed the edito color scheme to a dark one and it looks nice but the side panel, konsol, and other windows are still bright white which doesn't look good. Is there a way to change their colors?

[image]

If not I'd appreciate suggestions for other editors that have complete dark themes and good RTL support; so sublime doesn't do :(.

Thank you

Comment: by the way this isn't really  a tex problem ;)

Comment: That image doesn't show the Konsole part. With my config, the log & messages are on a white background, but the Konsole has a black background. I find this quite useful to easily distinguish them. However, you probably want to change the settings for KDE generally. If you are not using KDE as a desktop, you will probably need to first install a package which provides configuration options for KDE applications. (I mean a package from your distro, obviously - not a LaTeX package.) Or you can do it in configuration files using the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Color

[image: colors to change]

Note that this will change the appearance all KDE applications!

Answer (score -1):

I just managed to solve a color problem in kile (i'm using a dark theme on ubuntu and the text in kile side panel had no contrast) using the KDE System Settings which can be found in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Go to > `Application Appearence` -> `Colors(sidebar)` -> `Colors` and try to change the background color.

Hope it can be useful.