# Is it possible to invert the colors in Kile's live preview?

Tags: color, kile, preview

I like to use a dark theme for Kile, but the live PDF preview window (which is a great feature) is very bright.  Is there any way to make it dark, or set the background black, or invert the colors, or soemthing like that?

Comment: You can adjust the colors of every theme in kile... So yes it is possible I suppose... If you don't find the way in the settings I will check later in another pc of mine with kile installed... I haven't live PDF window there... but it doesn't matter if you adjust the colors you want one by one in the theme you like the live PDF colors I suppose

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to change the viewer's background or the viewer to invert PDF colors?

Answer (score 1):

I found on my PC that colors can be changed like this

> Settings -> Configure kile -> Editor ->Fonts & colors

If you adjust them from that section while you are still using the theme that fits your live PDF needs (the lighter), I suppose you will not have the specific problem (because the theme will remain light but the colors of the real output in the editing window will be adjusted to darker colors).

Possible in the new version there is a menu

> Settings -> Configure kile -> PDF Viewer ->Fonts & colors

and in this case may be thinks are even simpler

PS: I used that to have a lighter color between brackets (bracket highlight) than the text area and the line color and it was a nice feature because you can see where your brackets are closing... Do this at least if you don't find my answer useful otherwise (I have no live PDF viewer)

Comment: @TeXnician, does it mean that the menu is different, or that is the same but changing the background font will change live PDF preview font too? I only can imagine these two options. If so, please confirm to delete my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not understand your comment. But I reread the OP and it's not very clear what is actually referred to, hence I did leave a comment asking for what the OP tries to achieve. So you should not delete until we have a reaction by the OP.

Comment: @TeXnician, you made me find out what possibly was not clear in my answer and edited the answer... May be you will get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF output can easily be inverted by changing Configure Viewer > Accessibility > Change colours > Colour Mode > Invert colours, However the question says live preview window which is controlled by

Settings > Configure Kile > Tools > Preview > Quick Preview in Bottom Bar Background colour > Basic colors = anything you like

You can also change dpi for larger/smaller and change it for Selection, Environment or Maths

The only setting is background so I don't think you could invert unless you set the text to white, which could cause issues with down stream PDF generation, so I would suggest a grey tone whilst previewing. there was a similar request [discussed here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245940/kile-change-color-scheme-for-panels?rq=1)

On further testing Quick preview can call up Okular which also has Accessibility > Change colours > colour Mode > Invert colours so I guess its down to which window your using to preview.